# How i can resolve error 0x800700e9 with MS SQL Server full-text search?

Tags: sql, database, windows, full-text-search, sql-server-2014

When i try execute

```
SELECT * 
FROM sys.dm_fts_parser 
(N'"Additivity of measures is not exactly a data warehouse design problem. 
However, you have to realize which aggregate functions you will use 
in reports for which measure, and which aggregate functions 
you will use when aggregating over which dimension."', 1033, 5, 0);
```

or `EXEC sp_fulltext_service 'restart_all_fdhosts'`
i get next error message:

```
Msg 30046, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_fulltext_service, Line 171
SQL Server encountered error 0x800700e9 while communicating with full-text filter daemon host (FDHost) process. Make sure that the FDHost process is running. To re-start the FDHost process, run the sp_fulltext_service 'restart_all_fdhosts' command or restart the SQL Server instance.
```

I have tried next actions:

```
1. Run SQL Full-text Filter Daemon Launcher as Local Service, Local System, Local User, Local Administrator;
2.Run SSMS as Administrator;
3. Installed SP2 for SQL Server 2014
```

No one of them didn't help me. Here is my logs. My system is Windows 7 x64, SQL Server 2014.
1. SQL Server Logs after error:

```
Date,Source,Severity,Message
09/17/2018 22:30:02,spid53,Unknown,A new instance of the full-text filter daemon host process has been successfully started.
09/17/2018 22:28:55,spid53,Unknown,Using 'xpstar.dll' version '2014.120.5000' to execute extended stored procedure 'xp_instance_regread'. This is an informational message only; no user action is required.
09/17/2018 22:28:55,spid53,Unknown,Attempting to load library 'xpstar.dll' into memory. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
09/17/2018 22:28:20,spid52,Unknown,Using 'xpsqlbot.dll' version '2014.120.2000' to execute extended stored procedure 'xp_qv'. This is an informational message only; no user action is required.
09/17/2018 22:28:20,spid52,Unknown,Attempting to load library 'xpsqlbot.dll' into memory. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
```

2. Windows events:

```
Date,Source,Severity,Message,Log ID,Process ID,Mail Item ID,Account ID,Last Modified,Last Modified By,Category,Event,User,Computer
09/17/2018 22:31:45,Service Control Manager,Information,Служба "Служба регистрации ошибок Windows" перешла в состояние Остановлена.,,,,,,,(0),7036,,Juares-ПК
09/17/2018 22:30:03,Service Control Manager,Information,Служба "Служба автоматического обнаружения веб-прокси WinHTTP" перешла в состояние Остановлена.,,,,,,,(0),7036,,Juares-ПК
09/17/2018 22:30:02,spid53,Unknown,A new instance of the full-text filter daemon host process has been successfully started.,,,,,,,,,,
09/17/2018 22:30:02,MSSQLSERVER,Information,A new instance of the full-text filter daemon host process has been successfully started.,,,,,,,(2),30090,Juares-ПК\Juares,Juares-ПК
09/17/2018 22:29:45,Service Control Manager,Information,Служба "Служба регистрации ошибок Windows" перешла в состояние Работает.,,,,,,,(0),7036,,Juares-ПК
09/17/2018 22:28:55,spid53,Unknown,Using 'xpstar.dll' version '2014.120.5000' to execute extended stored procedure 'xp_instance_regread'. This is an informational message only; no user action is required.,,,,,,,,,,
09/17/2018 22:28:55,spid53,Unknown,Attempting to load library 'xpstar.dll' into memory. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.,,,,,,,,,,
09/17/2018 22:28:55,MSSQLSERVER,Information,Using 'xpstar.dll' version '2014.120.5000' to execute extended stored procedure 'xp_instance_regread'. This is an informational message only; no user action is required.,,,,,,,(2),8128,Juares-ПК\Juares,Juares-ПК
09/17/2018 22:28:55,MSSQLSERVER,Information,Attempting to load library 'xpstar.dll' into memory. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.,,,,,,,(2),33090,Juares-ПК\Juares,Juares-ПК
09/17/2018 22:28:20,spid52,Unknown,Using 'xpsqlbot.dll' version '2014.120.2000' to execute extended stored procedure 'xp_qv'. This is an informational message only; no user action is required.,,,,,,,,,,
09/17/2018 22:28:20,spid52,Unknown,Attempting to load library 'xpsqlbot.dll' into memory. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.,,,,,,,,,,
09/17/2018 22:28:20,MSSQLSERVER,Information,Using 'xpsqlbot.dll' version '2014.120.2000' to execute extended stored procedure 'xp_qv'. This is an informational message only; no user action is required.,,,,,,,(2),8128,Juares-ПК\Juares,Juares-ПК
09/17/2018 22:28:20,MSSQLSERVER,Information,Attempting to load library 'xpsqlbot.dll' into memory. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.,,,,,,,(2),33090,Juares-ПК\Juares,Juares-ПК
```

Please, Help me!!!!!

Comment: https://chrismay.org/2009/02/26/sql-server-encountered-error-0x80070422-fixed/ This link might be helpful.

Comment: I have done it, but it was without success